# Trouble with API Gateway to Lambda using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am using the Python CDK to deploy a Lambda function triggered by an API call. Here is my code:

`app.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from aws_cdk import core

from cvsg_app_bff.usermanagement import UserManagementStack

app = core.App()
UserManagementStack(app, "UserManagementStack")

app.synth()
```

My stack:

```py
class UserManagementStack(core.Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    # Lambda functions
    create_new_user: _lambda.Function = _lambda.Function(self, "newUserLambdaHandler",
                                                            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
                                                            handler="usermanagement.create_new_user",
                                                            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda_functions")
                                                            )

    # API gateway setup
    user_apis = api_gw.LambdaRestApi(self, 'UserManagementAPIs', handler=create_new_user, proxy=False)

    user_apis.root.resource_for_path('user').add_method('POST', api_gw.LambdaIntegration(create_new_user))
```

File with the Lambda functions:

```py
def format_return(status_code, response_body):
    response = {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'body': response_body
    }
    print("Response: ", str(response))
    return response


def is_admin(event):
    # todo: not implemented yet!
    return True


def get_event_body(event):
    print(json.dumps(event))
    return json.loads(event["body"])


def create_new_user(event, context):
    request_body = get_event_body(event)
    if is_admin(event):
        return format_return(200, request_body)
    else:
        return format_return(403, "Not Unauthorised for this operation")
```

When I deploy and hit the endpoint, I get a 502 Bad Gateway response with this message

```json
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I had a look at the CloudWatch logs, and I can see the correct response printed in the `format_response` method but the response from the client hitting the endpoint is always 502.

How do I get the API gateway to return the correct response?

Comment: What is the final value that your Lambda function is returning?

Comment: The create_new_user is the lambda handler. The returns from the function is what the lambda should returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that your Lambda function is returning an incorrect response.  Lambda functions called by API Gateway via Lambda Proxy Integrations need to return a JSON object in the following format:

```py
{
    "isBase64Encoded": True|False,
    "statusCode": <status code>,
    "headers": {
        "header-name": "header-value",
        # ...
    },
    "body": "{\"your\":\"data\"}" # <--- MUST be a string, NOT an object
}
```

Your `create_new_user` function returns `format_return(200, request_body)`, where `request_body` is the result of `get_event_body`, which returns **`json.loads`** (which returns a **dict**, not a string).

Changing `get_event_body` like so should do the trick:

```py
def get_event_body(event):
    print(json.dumps(event))
    return json.dumps(event["body"])
```

Comment: Not using a proxy integration. What should a lambda return if it is not a setup as a proxy. from my code ```user_apis = api_gw.LambdaRestApi(self, 'UserManagementAPIs', handler=create_new_user, proxy=False)```

Comment: You are, actually. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/LambdaRestApi.html?highlight=lambdarestapi#aws_cdk.aws_apigateway.LambdaRestApi). _"Defines an API Gateway REST API with AWS Lambda proxy integration."_

Comment: Your main, if not only, issue, is that you're returning a Python object (namely a `dict`) as your `body` instead of a `str`.  I scratched my head for several hours over this on my own project a few weeks ago.

Comment: Oh I see, you specified `proxy=False`.  Either way, I believe the Lambda function needs to return the same body.

Comment: I actually meant to reply yesterday but I forgot all about it. Consider upvoting my answer in addition to accepting it... :)